Trying to properly modelize app settings in a MAUI app following MVVM architecture
Context:
I am working on a relatively simple MAUI app, which includes a Setting page allowing to customize the UX/UI of the app.
I am trying to make the best use of the functionalities of MAUI, while also trying to think ahead of the development of similar apps and for that reason I have created a class library which includes different utilities/UI elements regarding similar logic and including the handling of app settings.
I am using the IPreferences class to store the preferences, and basically mapping each of the setting to a ViewModel instance upon navigating the Setting page.
In a few words, I have a vertical list of elements for each setting, and when one element is clicked, a popup shows and list all of the available setting values for the user to select one.
The problem:
The way those settings values are to be displayed varies.
For example, a setting allows to change the color scheme of some UI elements, and I therefore need to modelize those color scheme for them to be displayed in the setting values list view.
Here is what the ViewModels definitions look like:
public partial class SettingValueViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public object _value;
}

public partial class SelectColorModeViewModel : SettingValueViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Color _restColor;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Color _warmupColor;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Color _workColor;
}

The Value property of the SettingValueViewModel corresponds to the setting value which is stored with the IPreferences service.
In this example, this would be a value of the ColorMode enumeration:
public enum ColorMode
{
    [Description("App colors")]
    AppColors,

    [Description("High contrast")]
    HighContrast
}

How I (poorly ?) solved the problem:
I have created the SettingsRepository class where I have mapped all the possible setting values (as they are stored/retrieved in IPreferences) to the appropriate ViewModel instance.
To pursue with the ColorMode example, here is what the mapping looks like for this setting:
    public static readonly Dictionary<object, SettingValueViewModel> ColorModeDictionary = new Dictionary<object, SettingValueViewModel>
    {
        {ColorMode.AppColors, new SelectColorModeViewModel()
        {
            Value = ColorMode.AppColors,
            RestColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.AppColorsTimerColorsTheme["RestColor"],
            WorkColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.AppColorsTimerColorsTheme["WorkColor"],
            WarmupColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.AppColorsTimerColorsTheme["WarmupColor"]
        } },
        {ColorMode.HighContrast, new SelectColorModeViewModel()
        {
            Value = ColorMode.HighContrast,
            RestColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.HighContrastTimerColorsTheme["RestColor"],
            WorkColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.HighContrastTimerColorsTheme["WorkColor"],
            WarmupColor = (Color)ToolkitConstants.HighContrastTimerColorsTheme["WarmupColor"]
        } }
    };

And then, I have a method which receives a setting value as a parameter (ColorMode.HighContrast) for example, and needs to return the appropriate ViewModel for it. For that I have implemented the GetSettingViewModel method which looks like this and that I will further explain after:
    public static SettingValueViewModel GetSettingViewModel(object settingValue)
    {
        Type type = settingValue.GetType();

        if (!SettingTypesDictionary.TryGetValue(type, out IDictionary dictionary))
        {
            throw new Exception("Setting type not registered.");
        }

        if (!dictionary.Contains(settingValue))
        {
            throw new Exception("Setting value not registered.");
        }

        return (SettingValueViewModel)dictionary[settingValue]!;
    }

As you can see, the method first retrieves the setting type, in order to know in which dictionary of settings values it should look for the ViewModel instance. As you can see the ColorMode Type is used to index the TimerColorModeDictionary, which I included above and that contains all the ViewModels necessary to display the setting values associated with the ColorMode setting.
    public static readonly Dictionary<Type, IDictionary> SettingTypesDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IDictionary>()
    {
        {typeof(TimerColorMode), TimerColorModeDictionary },
    };

-> This design works, but I am relatively unexperienced with both MAUI/XAML and mobile apps, and I feel like I probably missed some built-in mechanism which would be more efficient/readable/easier to maintain, or maybe not and this is an acceptable solution in the MVVM paradigm?
Any kind of input on this matter is greatly appreciated.

have you tried to categorize the usage into a predefined and custom settings ? where predefined settings will be defined once and reused, while custom settings (e.g. user-defined) will be changed at runtime. maybe this is what you're looking for ?
